How to get Microsoft fonts on Amazon linux docker image
We want to create a docker based version of our java webapp. Our first approach was to use ubuntu as base (ubuntu:latest), and install JDK and Tomcat as separately downloaded distributions. Our webapp also requires some Windows Fonts (Arial etc.). We found the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer and managed to install it via apt-get (solution found in another SO post):
RUN echo "ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get -y install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

That approach worked, but it had some remaining problems, like having to build tomcat-native library on the docker image since that library is not part of the tomcat distribution.
Eventually, we decided to use up a pre-built image with JDK and tomcat as base instead: tomcat:9.0.88-jdk17-corretto. This has pretty much everything we need, except for the Windows fonts (obviously).
But now, we are stuck with how to install the fonts package. The tomcat image is based on Amazon linux, and has neither apt-get or apk. The tools yum and rpm are available. However, the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available with yum.
When trying to install it with rpm, the build process simply fails without a specific error.
We also tried downloading the .rpm directly from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mscorefonts2/files/rpms/
But then the build fails with missing dependencies (xorg-x11-font-utils, cabextract). We managed to install the xorg-x11-font-utils via yum, but cabextract again is not available.
We downloaded a cabextract.rpm from cabextract.org.uk, but then the build fails again with missing dependencies for some glibc version. We did not manage to find out what package etc we need for glibc here.
We are really at a loss now. Can we get the Windows fonts in another way (short of "borrowing" and copying them from a windows machine) via yum or rpm? Or can we maybe get apt-get (or apk or something) on Amazon linux to use the method we did with the ubuntu image?
